# Virtual host is not working in nginx ubuntu 18.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

Recently I setup ubuntu 18.04 in my pc. I tried to create a virtual host in Nginx. First I create a conf file which name leave_application.conf. Then I enabled this and write-host in `etc/hosts`. but when I hit the server name in a browser it is not working. The Error log is

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/leave_application/public/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/html/leave_application/public/index.php on line 24" while
>   reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server:
>   leave_application.ck, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "www.leave_application.ck"

## leave_application.conf

```
server {
        listen   80; 

    root /var/www/html/leave_application/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name leave_application.ck www.leave_application.ck;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

## Hosts

```
    127.0.0.1    localhost
    127.0.0.1    bs28
    127.0.0.1        www.leave_application.ck


    ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

## Get this output in the browser

```
This page isn’t working www.leave_application.ck is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `vendor/autoload.php` is missing, to fix this the following command can be run:

```
composer install
```

to install composer the following guide can be used: 
https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: already tried, dump-autoload also be tried. But the error has still now.

Comment: solved. Change Ownership of public folder 
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/html/partex_star/public`
And read permission to Nginx root directory `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/`.
Then It works fine.